# SQL data truncation when removing set options

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm attempting to remove a few options from a SET datatype. I already confirmed there are no rows in the database using those options. Somehow, I'm still getting a data truncation error:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
CHANGE `status` `status` set('Init','TimedOut','Processing','Unknown','Validate','Duplicate','Remove');

Error in query (1265): Data truncated for column 'status' at row 121393
```

But if I check row 121393:

```
SELECT status FROM myTable WHERE id=121393;

+--------+
| status |
+--------+
|        |
+--------+
```

It's empty, which certainly doesn't seem invalid to me. What's going on here, and how can I fix it?

Additional notes:

The original datatype of `status` is a set with two additional options, in the exact order shown below:
`set('Init','TimedOut','Processing','Unused','Unknown','Validate','Duplicate','Remove','Unused2')`

Comment: try this, `UPDATE myTable SET status = NULL WHERE id = 121393;`
and then try to delete again

Comment: I'm able to set it to NULL, but I still get the same error when I run the ALTER TABLE command

Comment: please verify, Before running the ALTER TABLE statement, verify that the status column has the data type of SET. If it is not already a SET data type, you will need to modify the column's data type to SET before attempting the alteration.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT status FROM myTable;
UPDATE myTable SET status = 'Init' WHERE status = 'Unknown';

Comment: @lareb Yes, it has a SET datatype. Added more details to the main post.

Comment: @GehanFernando the "Select distinct" shows a NULL value, empty value, and a handful of valid options (with neither of the Unused values). I can't run that update statement - there's rows with a correct "unknown" status that I don't want to touch.

Comment: Query for records where status not in ('Init','TimedOut','Processing','Unknown','Validate','Duplicate','Remove') and status is not null. If this returns any records then those are the ones you need to fix

Comment: I suspect that what your query error refers to as "row 121393" is not specifically the row with "id = 121393" ...?  My guess is that you potentially have some records with a "status" value of "Unused" or "Unused2" .... so maybe the data truncation error is a bit of a red herring (sorry, I'm not 100% familiar with mariadb)

Comment: @NickW That won't work - an empty value is valid. Over 100k rows have that. Also, that would return every row with multiple values (this is a set, not an enum). It's only seems to be one row that causes an error, and it appears empty as shown above.

Comment: @Craig If I have a row with "Unused" or "Unused2", it doesn't appear in the previously mentioned "select distinct" command. Not 100% sure on the row part, but "id" is the primary key, so I'd expect  that to be correct.

Comment: Hi @Reggie - yes, I know "id" might be your primary key, but I'm still not 100% sure that the DB's understanding of each row number would correspond exactly with the "id" value - I guess it depends on if your "id" values are exactly sequently from 1 to 121393 (with no missing values)

Comment: Anyhow, that may be beside the point.  Googling a bit about that error message in mariadb, it seems like it's an error message that often appears for things where the situation is not exactly "data truncation".  Can you see if you still get the same error message by only removing "Unused" or "Unused2" - one at a time - from your SET statement?

Comment: @Craig Unfortunately I can't really test this anymore - I reloaded the latest database backup from prod in my testing environment for unrelated reasons, and now the alter table command does work. Not sure if the database was corrupted in my test environment or what (I've had some strange (though I thought unrelated) issues on that VM in the past), but I'll take it I guess.

Comment: @Reggie - a strange one, then.  Oh, well, life rolls on!

Comment: In a normal database "row" is not "id". It might be different for Maria but it seems like an assumption that should be tested.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% if it was a coincidence or what, but dropping the database and loading the latest copy from production worked. Note that the row with ID 121393 had the same value in both environments, so I wonder if there was some form of corruption loading a new copy fixed.

If someone runs into this in the future, using `mysqldump` and reloading the whole database might be a valid option.